# Unable to connect to hidden SSID

Tags: wireless, ralink

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my HP mini 110, but unfortunately I'm unable to connect to hidden SSID while it works fine with non hidden wireless. The wireless device is RaLink RT3090. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 10.10 and have similar problems.

Run iwconfig and see if your ESSID is set. If not, run

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "network name"
```

where you replace "network name" by the essid of your network.

This works for me. It seems that Network Manager doesn't do this correctly
for hidden networks.